# How to delete a password filed when sesstion time has reached 60sec in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have developed a login page where OTP is generated for every login of the user .The following is a button action , I have created a "generate" button once clicked it would starts a session timer and after 60 sec it should delete the varchar present in the database.

**PHP Code for button :**

```
if(isset($_POST['generate']))
      {
        session_start();
         $_SESSION['login_time'] > 60 ;
         {
          $sql = "DELETE password WHERE username = ajaisandy " ;
         }
```

Here the "password" represent the column name , once the user enters the "generate button" the session starts and gives a time period of 60 sec . The user is suppose to receive the OTP via sms and should sign in within this time if not the password stored in the DB is deleted and once again he has to perform this sequence to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use UPDATE instead of DELETE, also you are missing `if ($_SESSION['login_time'] > 60)`

```
if(isset($_POST['generate']))
{
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['login_time'] > 60)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET password='' WHERE username = ajaisandy " ;
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: its creating an error " Undefined index: login_time "

Comment: that means session value for "login_time" is not set, where have you set value of $_SESSION['login_time'] ?

Comment: you can assign $_SESSION['login_time'] = 60; in login page

Comment: Actually this code is placed in the login page , the session should be started once the button has been clicked and should end after 60sec. How to start the timer after the button action has been performed ???

Comment: so you can assign $_SESSION['login_time'] = 60; in your above code and to check this value, you can write on AJAX function which will check the $_SESSION['login_time'] with current time and call this AJAX function using setInterval() javascript function

Comment: am sorry am not sure how to perform an AJAX function . Is there any method that while starting the session it should check with the current time in the computer or the server then after the time has expired it should delete the varchar in the DB ..

Comment: you can check the session value at the top of each page or can create one common file and include it in every page, but it will be only checked whenever user browse the pages.

Comment: I dnt want to place session in every page . All I want is to start a timer after the BUTTON has been clicked , after reaching a particular time it should perform the action of updating the password column to **null**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UPDATE` instead of `DELETE`:

```
UPDATE your_table SET password = null WHERE username = ?
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['generate']))
      {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login_time'] = 5;
        if($_SESSION['login_time'] > 5 )
         {
          $sql = "UPDATE user_login SET password='' WHERE username = ajaisandy " ;
        mysql_query($sql);
         }
} `


But the varchar is not cleared after the 5 sec ..

Answer (score 1):

And whats the condition for deleting. I guess putting an if condition in `$_SESSION['login_time'] > 60` would be helpful. and are you sure about the time you are using?

first start your timer with-

```
$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
```

now edit time checking in your code-

```
if(time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 60)
    {
     $sql = "DELETE password WHERE username = ajaisandy " ;
    }
```

Comment: sorry am not sure about the time , the thing is it should start the timer when the generate button has been clicked and after 60sec it should delete the password varachar

Comment: i have edited my answer. have a look! you can start your timer like this.

Comment: I guess you already accepted some other answer, if you got your answer then, whats that worrying you now?

Comment: I accepted for the SQL query . The thing is I need to start a timer once the button action is performed , after reaching 60sec I should declare a statement inside the if condition